# Google ReCaptcha not loading prior to jsx component rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recaptcha

I'm trying to create a react component to handle my recaptcha. I need to use the data-callback in order to set the value of my component since we're not using form tags. What happens is that through Google's recaptcha they load the field through an iframe. This means I don't have access to the textarea that contains the response from Google. I need to get the value of the textarea only after it's been validated. I'm prevented from doing so because the API is not loading prior to my react component rendering. If I try to use grecaptcha in my component it's undefined. However, after the page loads I can use grecaptcha in the console.

The way I'm currently trying to use recaptcha, as shown below, does not work. The object grecaptcha (the one created by google) is undefined, and data-callback never gets called.

I would prefer to shy away from using a plugin or anything from github. This seems like it shouldn't be that complicated. I do have access to lodash if anything there would help, as well as react-addons.

This is in the body tags at the bottom

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

Here is the jsx for the React component.

```js
(function() {
"use strict";

/**
 * Represents an HTML text element
 */
class Captcha extends COS.Input.Base
{
    getCaptchaResponse() {
        alert("working");
    }

    renderEdit()
    {
        return (
            <div
                ref="captcha"
                id="captcha"
                name="captcha"
                data-sitekey="6Lc9fg4TAAAAAGYyFskow-g2b4IQ_rLvsLkHicuS"
                data-callback={this.getCaptchaResponse}
                className="g-recaptcha"></div>
        );
    }

}

    Captcha.makeDefaultProps({
    // Extend Default Props here
    });

    COS.Input.Captcha = Captcha;
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out with some help outside of stackoverflow. I wanted to come back and resolve this. This was a different problem than I initially understood. I misunderstood how the callback function was used. It needed to be a string of the name of a global function. However, this didn't help me at all because I need the response inside of the Captcha class.

The code below in essence attaches my callback to the window, then after the component mounts it renders the recaptcha. I now have my response inside of the class and can set the value of the component for submit in my scenario of not using form tags

This is the footer line now

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=getCaptchaResponse&render=explicit' async defer></script>
```

```js
(function() {
    "use strict";

    /**
     * Represents a Google ReCaptcha
     */
    class Captcha extends COS.Input.Base {

      getCaptchaResponse(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }

      renderEdit() {
        window['getCaptchaResponse'] = () => {
          grecaptcha.render("captcha", {
            sitekey: "6Lc9fg4TAAAAAGYyFskow-g2b4IQ_rLvsLkHicuS",
            callback: (this.getCaptchaResponse) ? this.getCaptchaResponse : undefined,
          });
        };

        return ( < div id = "captcha"
          ref = "captcha"
          name = "captcha"
          data-onloadcallbackname = {
            'getCaptchaResponse'
          }
          data-verifycallbackname = {
            'getCaptchaResponse'
          } >
          < /div>
            );
        }

    }

    Captcha.makeDefaultProps({
        / / Extend Default Props here
        });

      COS.Input.Captcha = Captcha;
    })();
```